# is it safe to replace armeabi-v7a with armeabi-v7a-hard?

Tags: android, android-ndk

i am think that all device that support armeabi-v7a should be able to support armeabi-v7a-hard. if so, why do not we just abandon armeabi-v7a or just use armeabi-v7a-hard to replace armeabi-v7a for NDK that >=xx(9c?)

Answer (score 4):

-msoft-float and -mhard-float do not toggle between hardware and software floating point.

The actual difference is the calling convention on how arguments are passed to functions.

This means that -mhard-float is only slightly faster (both use hardware floating point implementation), but -msoft-float has better ABI compatibility.

For a complete overview, see this blogpost:
http://blog.alexrp.com/2014/02/18/android-hard-float-support/
(or its [backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20180414111619/http://blog.alexrp.com/2014/02/18/android-hard-float-support/) on web archive.)

**UPDATE**
The hard float ABI has now been [deprecated](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/353e653824b79c43b948429870d0abeedebde386/docs/HardFloatAbi.md) by Google.

Comment: in what situation that -msoft-float is ok while -mhard-float has problem for armeabi-v7a abi? it seems as long as the NDK support -mhard-float, they are the same compatibility. that is it is safe to use armeabi-v7a-hard to replace armeabi-v7a for NDK >9c. why not NKD just do the replace?

Comment: From linked article: "to utilize the hard float ABI, you must either compile every last component of your application as hard float (the -mhard-float GCC/Clang switch), or mark individual functions with the appropriate __attribute__ to indicate the desired ABI." If you don't link in any binary libs, you could be ok.

Comment: The blogpost is dead